# Allowing a td content to go on the next column without colspan

Tags: html, css

I have the following table :

```
<table width="260px" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="30%">
      <span>this is a foobar text that shoud create a multiline text
      </span>
    </td>
    <td width="70%">Pas vraiment</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that I want to allow the `span`tag's content to go in the next column without using `colspan`.

How can I do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: This does not make sense - why don't you want to use the `colspan` attribute? And what should happen with the contents of the second `td`?

Comment: I can't edit the table css (It's too long to explain). Well, the span content, which would be on the two columns, should be over (z-index) any other content.

Comment: colspan was made for this ! why can't you use it ?

Comment: colspan is no css ... seems like a xss attempt for me.

Comment: @remibourgarel Please, if you can't find the answer, try and be polite.

Comment: @TheBens well i'm trying to help, maybe your reason why you can't use colspan is not a good one, and the reason you gave would be the reasons I gave if I was trying a xss attack. AFAIK i'm still polite, sorry if It seems like I'm not.

Comment: @remibourgarel you know, if everyone explains the architecture is working, I think it will be a real mess. This why I created this little example as a showcase.

Comment: @TheBens it's an architecture requirement that forbid you to use colspan ? I don't see any other solution than colspan if you can't use css either. Can you do inline css ?

Comment: @remibourgarel I cannot edit the table css, but for the span yes ...

Comment: @TheBens haaa ! sorry didn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/KSVyW/

I just made each cell display inline. It's not really a table at this point, but it will allow your text to overflow...